# Cannot install RHQ

Tags: jboss7.x, rhq

I am trying to install RHQ Version 4.12 according to the [book](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/RHQ/RHQ+Server+Installation).

It seems simple enough, but I cannot get it to work. The underlying Jboss AS does not seem to boot up and the installation procedure stops with:

```
15:39:17,223 ERROR [org.rhq.enterprise.server.installer.Installer] The installer will now exit due to previous errors: java.lang.Exception: Cannot obtain client connection to the RHQ app server!!
at org.rhq.enterprise.server.installer.InstallerServiceImpl.testModelControllerClient(InstallerServiceImpl.java:1121) [rhq-installer-util-4.12.0.jar:4.12.0]
at org.rhq.enterprise.server.installer.InstallerServiceImpl.preInstall(InstallerServiceImpl.java:221) [rhq-installer-util-4.12.0.jar:4.12.0]
at org.rhq.enterprise.server.installer.InstallerServiceImpl.test(InstallerServiceImpl.java:146) [rhq-installer-util-4.12.0.jar:4.12.0]
at org.rhq.enterprise.server.installer.Installer.doInstall(Installer.java:90) [rhq-installer-util-4.12.0.jar:4.12.0]
at org.rhq.enterprise.server.installer.Installer.main(Installer.java:57) [rhq-installer-util-4.12.0.jar:4.12.0]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:292) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:455) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012174: Could not connect to remote://127.0.0.1:9999. The connection failed
```

I found some threads over at the jboss forum, but they did not offer any help. Example would be https://developer.jboss.org/thread/230622

I am running this on a vagrant machine with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Oracle Java 1.7.0_65-b17. I attempt the installation running `bin/rhqctl install`

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: What value did you enter for rhq-server.properties in the server config file?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to check the server.log file? It would be interesting to know why the server did not start (if it didn't).